# Apex Oracle How to Create a Conditionally Mandatory Column

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am new to using Apex Oracle to create a table and insert values in it. I need to create a column that is only mandatory if there is a value for another column in the table. How could I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

@Littlefoots' answer (as always) works just fine, but this can just as well be solved with a check constraint on the table.

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  id     NUMBER GENERATED AS IDENTITY,
  col1  VARCHAR2(10),
  col2  VARCHAR2(10));

Table TEST_TABLE created.

ALTER TABLE test_table ADD CONSTRAINT test_table_c1 check ((col1 IS NOT NULL AND col2 IS NOT NULL) OR col1 IS NULL);

Table TEST_TABLE altered.

INSERT INTO test_table(col1,col2) VALUES (NULL,NULL);

1 row inserted.

INSERT INTO test_table(col1,col2) VALUES ('x','x');

1 row inserted.

INSERT INTO test_table(col1,col2) VALUES ('x',NULL);

Error report -
ORA-02290: check constraint (SAMPLEAPPS.TEST_TABLE_C1) violated
```

Answer (score 0):

On a database level, you'd do that with a trigger. Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (cond_mand number,     -- conditionally mandatory column
  3     other_col number);    -- other column (affects COND_MAND)

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_biu_test
  2    before insert or update on test
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    if :new.other_col is not null and :new.cond_mand is null then
  6       raise_application_error(-20000, 'OTHER_COL has value, so COND_MAND is mandatory');
  7    end if;
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into test (cond_mand, other_col) values (1, 1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test (cond_mand, other_col) values (null, 2);
insert into test (cond_mand, other_col) values (null, 2)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: OTHER_COL has value, so COND_MAND is mandatory
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG_BIU_TEST", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG_BIU_TEST'


SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you! When using Oracle Apex, what would I originally set other_col to? Would I just say its nullable (not mandatory) for the time being until I run the SQL command?

Comment: Yes. Oracle will raise an error (like in my 2nd example) if you try to insert an "invalid" combination.